# Autocomplete with some items disabled

Tags: angular, autocomplete

I want to use an autocomplete component (I'm currently trying "[ng2-completer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-completer)") to make a list where some items in this list are displayed as disabled.
How can I do it?

I am currently using the ng2-completer with the keydown event in the html, which calls a function where a "disabled class" is added only to items that contain a specific word.

The problem is that the class is displayed only when you change the focus with the arrow keys (keyboard) and not with the mouse.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), ideally in an online code editor such as [Stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com).